# Light weight machine to machine communication with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, iot

I am running a LwM2M server using LwM2M Leshan library. How can I run a LwM2M client on an Arduino board to connect with LwM2M Leshan server ? Please note that Leshan LwM2M client implementation is written in Java, and so cannot be run on an Arduino.

Comment: Is the spec opensource? if so, is there a problem preventing you from implementing it yourself? Also, from a limited search I found this : http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/control-an-arduino-from-java/240163864 if it is possible to connect your arduino to another computer then that might be an easier solution

Comment: yes leshan is an opensource and I already went through that site,but I couldn't find any solution from it.

Comment: Can you not implement a leshan client in whatever language arduino uses?

Comment: No I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that unlike Raspberry Pi(micro processor based), an Arduino( 8 bit AVR micro controller based) doesn't offer Linux software stack. All it gives is simplified C/C++ support with a set of convenience libraries. And so you cannot run the LwM2M Leshan Java client on Arduino.

Theoretically you can run a C based LwM2M client implementation like Eclipse Wakaama([1](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama)) project on Arduino. But absence of Linux software stack will make porting Wakaama to Arduino a not so straight forward process for beginners. You will need Arduino compatible libraries for CoAP([2](https://github.com/internetofhomethings/ESP8266-Triple-Server)) and possibly Arduino OTA([3](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/2.1.0/libraries/ArduinoOTA)) as suggested in this thread([4](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wakaama-dev/msg00212.html)).

In case you happen to be working with Arduino Yun( offers Linux software stack), the porting of Wakaama will be much easier as shown in this post([5](https://github.com/msangoi/wakaama/wiki/Run-Wakaama-on-the-Arduino-Yun)).

Answer (score 0):

For embedded client code in C, you should look at Eclipse [Wakaama](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama). It should be fairly straightforward to port on Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Try porting [AwaLWM2M](https://github.com/ConnectivityFoundry/AwaLWM2M) static API for constrained devices, which is a lightweight LWM2M client in C.
I have not tried implementing this, but you can give it a try. Do share the results, so that others can get help from your work.